# Excel VBA: Macro to only export non blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

Good day everyone,

I have this macro, which exports all cells with formulas, BUT with blank outputs.

I only want the cells displaying as non blank to export. Any ideas?

```
Sub Export_A()

Dim sPath As String
Dim SFile As String
Dim nLog As Integer

sPath = "C:\AAAWork\"
SFile = sPath & ActiveSheet.Range("P9") & ".txt"

nfile = FreeFile

Open SFile For Output As #nfile

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set ThisCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)

If ThisCell.Text <> "" Then
 '   sInDate = ThisCell.Text

    'sOutDate = Format(ThisCell.Value, "mm/yyyy")
    sOutDate = Format(ThisCell.Value, "yyyy-mm")
    'stemp = """" & sOutDate & """" this gives the date the " in the    
beginning and end
    stemp = "" & sOutDate & ""


    For j = 1 To 10
        If j = 1 Or j = 2 Or j = 9 Then
            stemp = stemp & ";" & ThisCell.Offset(0, j)
        Else
            'stemp = stemp & "," & """" & ThisCell.Offset(0, j) & """" This 
gives every value a " beginning and end
            stemp = stemp & ";" & ThisCell.Offset(0, j)
        End If
    Next
End If
Print #nfile, stemp
Next
Close #nfile


MsgBox ("Completed a file called " & SFile & " has been generated")

End Sub
```

This is an interesting way of exporting to CSV, but it was inherited and does everything else very well.

Comment: I don't see a "Write #nfile" line. How do you write to the file?

Comment: Hi, it should write from
    Open SFile For Output As #nfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the Write line at the end of the For loop

```
Sub Export_A()

Dim sPath As String
Dim SFile As String
Dim nLog As Integer

sPath = "C:\AAAWork\"
SFile = sPath & ActiveSheet.Range("P9") & ".txt"

nfile = FreeFile

Open SFile For Output As #nfile

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set ThisCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)

If ThisCell.Text <> "" Then
 '   sInDate = ThisCell.Text

    'sOutDate = Format(ThisCell.Value, "mm/yyyy")
    sOutDate = Format(ThisCell.Value, "yyyy-mm")
    'stemp = """" & sOutDate & """" this gives the date the " in the beginning and end
    stemp = "" & sOutDate & ""


    For j = 1 To 10
        stemp = stemp & ";" & ThisCell.Offset(0, j)
    Next

    Print #nfile, stemp

End If

Next
Close #nfile


MsgBox ("Completed a file called " & SFile & " has been generated")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

first you don't need this if statement as the output is the same if it's true or false

```
    If j = 1 Or j = 2 Or j = 9 Then
        stemp = stemp & ";" & ThisCell.Offset(0, j)
    Else
        'stemp = stemp & "," & """" & ThisCell.Offset(0, j) & """" This gives every value a " beginning and end
        stemp = stemp & ";" & ThisCell.Offset(0, j)
    End If
```

If the blanks are in the following columns you could change to code to:

```
    If ThisCell.Offset(0, j) <> "" Then
        stemp = stemp & ";" & ThisCell.Offset(0, j)
    End If
```

Which will skip blank columns

Comment: This macro now repeats the last non blank row, and repeats it for the same number of the blank rows. Ie. if I had 10 rows with non blank data, and 90 blank rows, it repeats row 10  90 times.