# Hide rows if no text on export to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple script for exporting a range to Excel:

```
`Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

 With Sheets("Summary").Range("B2:H83")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="F:\Export.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End With

End Sub
```

`
The issue is that certain rows may or may not be populated based on inputs in separate sheets. So for example Rows 34-42 could be populated, but more likely than not only Row 34 is populated. This leaves a lot of white space in the exported PDF.

I have no idea how to structure my code to check if there is info in the Row, and if not then to hide the row thereby eliminating white space

Comment: Hi you can verify the similar question posted here[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068309/excel-vba-macro-to-only-export-non-blank-cells)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have adjusted your script to hide blank rows. It checks only the range you mention above, in case it's a dynamic range you can let me know.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim rowCounter As Integer
Dim columnCounter As Integer
Dim blankFlag As Boolean

With sheets("Summary")
    'hide blank rows in 34-42 and 44-56 interval
    For rowCounter = 34 To 56
        blankFlag = True

        For columnCounter = 2 To 8
            If .Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter) <> "" Then
                blankFlag = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next columnCounter

        If blankFlag = True Then rows(rowCounter).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        If rowCounter = 42 then rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Next rowCounter

End With

With sheets("Summary").Range("B2:H83")
    'export to PDF
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:="F:\Export.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it a bit after testing it, was not sure if the hidden rows get exported to the PDF, but apparently they are not.

Comment: Thanks this works really well, the only thing is that I'm not looking to remove all empty rows since some add padding, rather only hide for Rows 34-42 and 44 to 56

Answer (score 1):

Better to hide all of the empty rows at once instead of hiding them individually on each iteration of the loop.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim mainRng As Range
    Set mainRng = sheets("Summary").Range("B2:H83")

    Dim unionRng As Range

    Dim roww As Range
    For Each roww In mainRng.rows
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(roww) = 0 Then
            If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, roww)
            Else
                Set unionRng = roww
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    mainRng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:="F:\Export.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

        Dim ShtSummary As Worksheet
        Dim i As Integer

        Set ShtSummary = Sheets("Summary")

        For i = 3 To 83
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(i)) = 0 Then
                ShtSummary.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If

        Next i

     With Sheets("Summary").Range("B2:H83")
        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="F:\Export.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

Good Luck.